# How to name radical

Tags: nomenclature, radicals

The name of biradical —CO—CH2–O—CH2–CO— is Oxybis (1-oxo-***2,1***-ethanediyl). Why is it wrong to write **1,2**-ethanediyl instead of **2,1**?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The relevant rule for the numbering in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069)* reads as follows.

> **P-15.3.1.2.2.4** Numbering of the components of a multipart di- or trivalent
> multiplicative substituent group, when necessary, is achieved by attributing lowest locants to the atoms that are at the end of the component nearest to the multiplied parent structure, except where the component has a fixed numbering. The locants attached to the multiplied parent structure are cited last. (…)

[image]